# How to print external images from ActionScript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

i have this script:

```
on (release) {
imprime = new PrintJob();
imprime.start();
imprime.addPage(papel_mc);
imprime.send();
delete imprime;
```

}

But, here i only print an MovieClip on my Stage called papel_mc. My Question is: How i can print an external JPG??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load it as a Bitmap and after you can add it to your papel_mc and print.

I'm not familiar with as2, so connot provide with a code, but i think [here at kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=321702) they almost solve the problem.

Comment: this script on Kirupa is AS3 i need it on AS2, but i'm try adapt this.... ty very much!